# How can i set a generic List as a property in a Neo4j stored procedure?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, stored-procedures, neo4j

I am making a Neo4j plugin with some stored procedures. One of these needs to take arguments of arbitrary type, and save them as properties on a Node. Naïvely I might do it like this

```kotlin
val props: Map<String, Any> = <procedure input>
props.forEach(node::setProperty)
```

This works fine for scalar types, but if the value is a List it fails with

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [[123]:java.util.ArrayList] is not a supported property value

since `setProperty` wants the value to be an Array. Simply casting the List to an Array results in an `Array<Any>` due to (I assume) type erasure.

I have this slightly clunky solution:

```kotlin
props.forEach { (key, value) ->
  if (value is Collection<*>) {
    val firstElement = value.firstOrNull()
    if (firstElement != null) {
      val arrayValue: Array<Any?> =
        java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(firstElement.javaClass, value.size) as Array<Any?>

      value.forEachIndexed { index, element -> arrayValue[index] = element }

      node.setProperty(key, arrayValue)
    } else {
      node.setProperty(key, emptyArray<Long>()) // Arrays need a type, so we just pick one
    }
  } else {
    node.setProperty(key, value)
  }
}
```

This works, but is there an easier way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin already has inbuilt function [toTypedArray()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html) . It will convert any collection to array without losing the type. Hope this is what you need.

```
var value = arrayListOf<String>("Foo","Bar")
var arrayValue : Array<String> = value.toTypedArray()
```

This is a part of [Kotlin Standard Library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/). You can find [latest version here.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Remember that `value` has type `Any` when it is passed to my procedure. And while I can check if it is a `Collection` and then call `toTypedArray` on it, that just gives me an `Array<Any>` which Neo4j rejects.

Comment: Havent worked on neo4j. You are saying that, your solution is working for you, but how?.
You have created Array<Any?> below and passing  it to node.setProperty. 
How it works if you pass Array<Any>?

      val arrayValue: Array<Any?> =
        java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(firstElement.javaClass, value.size) as Array<Any?>

      value.forEachIndexed { index, element -> arrayValue[index] = element }

      node.setProperty(key, arrayValue)

Comment: I'm a bit foggy on exactly why, but I think the `Array<Any?>` is just for the compiler's sake. The actual runtime type of `arrayValue` will be `Array<String>`, `Array<Long>` or whatever. See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37370819/1872981

Comment: Hmm , Okay then. I dont think any other ways would work for you without typecasting.